# Pandas printing ALL dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, pretty-print

This seems like a very simple problem, however it's driving me round the bend. I'm sure it should be solved by RTFM, but I've looked at the options and I can see the one to fix it.

I just want to print the dtypes of all columns, currently I'm getting:

```
print df.dtypes
#>
Date         object
Selection    object
Result       object
...
profit    float64
PL        float64
cumPL     float64
Length: 11, dtype: object
```

I've tried setting options `display.max_row`, `display.max_info_row`, `display.max_info_columns` all to no avail.

What am i doing wrong?

Pandas version = `0.13.1`

---

Update:

Turns out I was being and idiot and hadn't set `display.max_row` to a high enough value.

Solution was:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 20)
```

Comment: I think you've must have set it to a very low number yourself (the ``display.max_rows``), because that is 60 by default (so a series of 11 elements would never be truncated)

Comment: it was set to 10, i was being dumb.

Comment: When going for raw printouts, I usually default to something like `print dict(df.dtypes)`

Comment: How about columns?

Answer (score 70):

I tried this and worked:

```
df.info(verbose=True)
```

Answer (score 15):

Do this:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(df.dtypes)
```

Answer (score 10):

another way around is to group by dtype as follows:

```
x = df.columns.to_series().groupby(df.dtypes).groups
x
{dtype('object'): ['Date', 'Selection', 'Result'], dtype('float64'): ['profit', 'PL', 'cumPL']
```

Comment: how do you access the elements of that dictionary?