# Python Pandas: dtypes not show column types for all columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv data file with 101 columns and I would like to see the type for each column. I use

```
dat=pandas.read_csv("try.csv")
dat.dtypes
```

It returns only first and last 15 columns with types. All other columns are truncated. And there is ... in between

I wonder how can I see types for all columns?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What about `df.info()`, also try `pd.set_options('display.max_rows', 120)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are seeing a truncated output because pandas is protecting you from printing reams of information in the output. You can override this:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 120)
```

The default setting is 60

A list can be found here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html

and also related: [List of pandas options for method set_option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293536/list-of-pandas-options-for-method-set-option)

Answer (score 2):

I think a good way is this

```
dat.info(verbose=True)
```

as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52831020/2110769).

I think it is better than the [solution of EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28240155/2110769) since it does not force you to change the default display setting

Answer (score 0):

I think this is better way when in Jupyter notebook,

```html
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(pd.DataFrame(dat.dtypes).to_html()
```