# Printing all contents without ellipsis

Tags: pandas

When I try to print the columns,

```
print dataframe.columns
```

it shows me

```
Index([u'Id', u'Guid', u'HardDisksInfo', u'ServerVersion', u'Email',
       u'BackupServer', u'DataSizeQuota', u'HostRamSize', u'CpuModel',
       u'CpuSpeed',
       ...
       u'Post_Month', u'Geography', u'Region', u'Budget_Region',
       u'Product_Family', u'Product_Name', u'Product_Version', u'License_Type',
       u'Language', u'row_num'],
      dtype='object', length=131)
```

How do I make it shows all without the `...`?

Comment: If you are searching to print contents https://stackoverflow.com/a/25352191/429476

Answer (score 8):

You need set `display.max_seq_items` to `None` or some value higher as `100` - see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#available-options):

> **Option**: display.max_seq_items
> **Default**: 100
>
> **Function**: when pretty-printing a long sequence, no more then max_seq_items will be printed. If items are omitted, they will be denoted by the addition of ”...” to the resulting string. If set to None, the number of items to be printed is unlimited.

```
idx = [u'Id', u'Guid', u'HardDisksInfo', u'ServerVersion', u'Email',
       u'BackupServer', u'DataSizeQuota', u'HostRamSize', u'CpuModel',
       u'CpuSpeed',
       
       u'Post_Month', u'Geography', u'Region', u'Budget_Region',
       u'Product_Family', u'Product_Name', u'Product_Version', u'License_Type',
       u'Language', u'row_num']
idx = idx * 10
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=idx)

print (df.columns)
Index(['Id', 'Guid', 'HardDisksInfo', 'ServerVersion', 'Email', 'BackupServer',
       'DataSizeQuota', 'HostRamSize', 'CpuModel', 'CpuSpeed',
       ...
       'Post_Month', 'Geography', 'Region', 'Budget_Region', 'Product_Family',
       'Product_Name', 'Product_Version', 'License_Type', 'Language',
       'row_num'],
      dtype='object', length=200)
      
#temporaly display all columns
with pd.option_context('display.max_seq_items', None):
    print (df.columns)
```

```
Index(['Id', 'Guid', 'HardDisksInfo', 'ServerVersion', 'Email', 'BackupServer',
       'DataSizeQuota', 'HostRamSize', 'CpuModel', 'CpuSpeed', 'Post_Month',
       'Geography', 'Region', 'Budget_Region', 'Product_Family',
       'Product_Name', 'Product_Version', 'License_Type', 'Language',
       'row_num', 'Id', 'Guid', 'HardDisksInfo', 'ServerVersion', 'Email',
       'BackupServer', 'DataSizeQuota', 'HostRamSize', 'CpuModel', 'CpuSpeed',
       'Post_Month', 'Geography', 'Region', 'Budget_Region', 'Product_Family',
       'Product_Name', 'Product_Version', 'License_Type', 'Language',
       'row_num', 'Id', 'Guid', 'HardDisksInfo', 'ServerVersion', 'Email',
       'BackupServer', 'DataSizeQuota', 'HostRamSize', 'CpuModel', 'CpuSpeed',
       'Post_Month', 'Geography', 'Region', 'Budget_Region', 'Product_Family',
       'Product_Name', 'Product_Version', 'License_Type', 'Language',
       'row_num', 'Id', 'Guid', 'HardDisksInfo', 'ServerVersion', 'Email',
       'BackupServer', 'DataSizeQuota', 'HostRamSize', 'CpuModel', 'CpuSpeed',
       'Post_Month', 'Geography', 'Region', 'Budget_Region', 'Product_Family',
       'Product_Name', 'Product_Version', 'License_Type', 'Language',
       'row_num', 'Id', 'Guid', 'HardDisksInfo', 'ServerVersion', 'Email',
       'BackupServer', 'DataSizeQuota', 'HostRamSize', 'CpuModel', 'CpuSpeed',
       'Post_Month', 'Geography', 'Region', 'Budget_Region', 'Product_Family',
       'Product_Name', 'Product_Version', 'License_Type', 'Language',
       'row_num', 'Id', 'Guid', 'HardDisksInfo', 'ServerVersion', 'Email',
       'BackupServer', 'DataSizeQuota', 'HostRamSize', 'CpuModel', 'CpuSpeed',
       'Post_Month', 'Geography', 'Region', 'Budget_Region', 'Product_Family',
       'Product_Name', 'Product_Version', 'License_Type', 'Language',
       'row_num', 'Id', 'Guid', 'HardDisksInfo', 'ServerVersion', 'Email',
       'BackupServer', 'DataSizeQuota', 'HostRamSize', 'CpuModel', 'CpuSpeed',
       'Post_Month', 'Geography', 'Region', 'Budget_Region', 'Product_Family',
       'Product_Name', 'Product_Version', 'License_Type', 'Language',
       'row_num', 'Id', 'Guid', 'HardDisksInfo', 'ServerVersion', 'Email',
       'BackupServer', 'DataSizeQuota', 'HostRamSize', 'CpuModel', 'CpuSpeed',
       'Post_Month', 'Geography', 'Region', 'Budget_Region', 'Product_Family',
       'Product_Name', 'Product_Version', 'License_Type', 'Language',
       'row_num', 'Id', 'Guid', 'HardDisksInfo', 'ServerVersion', 'Email',
       'BackupServer', 'DataSizeQuota', 'HostRamSize', 'CpuModel', 'CpuSpeed',
       'Post_Month', 'Geography', 'Region', 'Budget_Region', 'Product_Family',
       'Product_Name', 'Product_Version', 'License_Type', 'Language',
       'row_num', 'Id', 'Guid', 'HardDisksInfo', 'ServerVersion', 'Email',
       'BackupServer', 'DataSizeQuota', 'HostRamSize', 'CpuModel', 'CpuSpeed',
       'Post_Month', 'Geography', 'Region', 'Budget_Region', 'Product_Family',
       'Product_Name', 'Product_Version', 'License_Type', 'Language',
       'row_num'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: I was surprised to find that this works for df.columns but not for df.dtypes.  Is there a solution that will show the full output for dtypes?

Comment: @graymatter same problem here, solved by setting 'display.max_rows'. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168416/pandas-printing-all-dtypes