# pandas select_dtypes not returning all columns of dtype

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm encountering strange behavior with select_dtypes in Pandas.

I am using a JupyterNotebook v6.0.1 with Python 3.7.4 on Ubuntu Linux.

I'm working with a [dataset of bulldozer auction results](https://www.kaggle.com/c/bluebook-for-bulldozers).

I started by importing the dataset into pandas dataframe from a csv file and dropped a couple of features that I knew that I would not want to use and limited the dataset by year because I wanted to use recent data.

```
drop_features = ['SalesID','ModelID','MachineID','fiProductClassDesc']

bulldozers_df = pd.read_csv("bluebook-for-bulldozers/Train.csv").drop(drop_features,axis=1)
bulldozers_df = bulldozers_df[pd.to_datetime(bulldozers_df['saledate']).dt.year > 2004]
```

Then I listed out the types of the columns.

```
bulldozers_df.dtypes.value_counts()

object     44
int64       3
float64     2
dtype: int64
```

Then I created a new synthetic column with a feature that I thought I would want to use.

```
bulldozers_df = bulldozers_df.assign(YearsMadeAgo = bulldozers_df['saledate'].astype('datetime64').dt.year - bulldozers_df['YearMade'].map(lambda x: bulldozers_df['YearMade'].mean() if pd.isna(x) else x))
```

And then, I checked the columns again.

```
SalePrice                     int64
datasource                    int64
auctioneerID                float64
YearMade                      int64
MachineHoursCurrentMeter    float64
UsageBand                    object
saledate                     object
fiModelDesc                  object
fiBaseModel                  object

(... additional features...)

Travel_Controls              object
Differential_Type            object
Steering_Controls            object
YearsMadeAgo                  int64
```

Then I decided to select the 'int64' columns. I expected to get 4 columns back: SalePrice, datasource,YearMade and YearsMadeAgo (the column that I made).

However, when I run the command, first I only get back SalePrice, datasource and YearMade.

Then, once I try again, pandas appears to break and just returns the index to me.

```
bulldozers_df.select_dtypes('int64')

SalePrice   datasource  YearMade
0   66000   121 2004
3   38500   121 2001
4   11000   121 2007
5   26500   121 2004
7   27000   121 2001
... ... ... ...
401120  10500   149 2005
401121  11000   149 2005
401122  11500   149 2005
401123  9000    149 2005
401124  7750    149 2005
```

```
bulldozers_df.select_dtypes('int64')
0
3
4
5
7
...
401120
401121
401122
401123
401124
```

Does anyone know what might be going on? df.select_dtypes appeared to work before I added the YearsMadeAgo column.

Just Hardware specs in case it is relevant, I have 24 GB of RAM with 20 GB free and 1.2% CPU usage with an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4460  CPU @ 3.20GHz.

Answer (score 0):

What environment are you using? Because pandas will visually truncate output to fit in a particular cell or terminal output.

Something like

```
bulldozers_df.info(verbose=True)
```

should work

also something like this

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(df.dtypes)
```

As shown here

[Pandas printing ALL dtypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168416/pandas-printing-all-dtypes)

Comment: I'm using JupyterNotebook v6.0.1. It's strange df.info() and df.dtypes return the correct information about the YearsMadeAgo column but df.select_dtypes('int64') will not return the YearsMadeAgo column even though it appears as 'int64' in the return values of df.info() and df.dtypes.

The first time I use df.select_dtypes('int64'), I get the original interger64 columns minus the new YearsMadeAgo one that I made. The second time I use df.select_dtypes('int64'), it breaks and just returns the index.